# Core plot Y axis majorgridline can only land on whole numbers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

In my Chart, the majorGridLines works fine for whole numbers, but when by range is between say 3.0 and 0.0 with 10 or so majorTickLocations. The tick locations are in the right spot, I.E approximately every 0.3, but the majorGridLines aren't in the same position as the Tick, they are just landing on the whole numbers 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 etc. How can I get the majorGridLines to work with unwhole numbers and be level with the tickLocations?

Code is below:

```
NSMutableSet *yLabels = [NSMutableSet set];
NSMutableSet *yMajorLocations = [NSMutableSet set];

for (int i=-1; i<numYAxisLabels; i++) {

        id jAsID = [NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)j];
        int jAsInt = [jAsID integerValue];

        CPTAxisLabel *label;
        if(majorIncrement < 1)
            label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", j] textStyle:y.labelTextStyle];
        else
            label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", jAsInt] textStyle:y.labelTextStyle];

        NSDecimal location = CPTDecimalFromFloat(j);
        label.tickLocation = location;
        label.offset = -y.majorTickLength - y.labelOffset;

        [yLabels addObject:label];
        [yMajorLocations addObject:jAsID];

        currTopYLabelLocation = j;
        j += majorIncrement;
    }
    y.axisLabels = yLabels;
    y.majorTickLocations = yMajorLocations;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tick locations are built from a series of `jAsID` values. In the code given in the question, `j` is cast to an integer value before creating the `NSNumber` object.

Comment: Thankyou Eric, that was it! My apologies, I thought it wasn't the case because the tickLocations were coming out fine.